# I can't find the solution to an 'list index out of range' error

Tags: python, list, indexing, error-handling, range

First of all, please keep in mind that this is my first time actually working on a project.

This code is for calculating the formula weight for chemical formulas with one-letter-long elements and one digit coefficients.
(for example, if you type in H2O1, it prints out 18)

I've tried lengthening intlength and changing the index for myatom and myatomnum.
The same error showed up everytime.

I cannot use any other functions, only the ones on the script.

```
atom = ['H', 'B', 'C', 'N', 'O', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'K']
atommass = [1, 10.8, 12, 14, 16, 19, 31, 32, 39.1]
myatom = []
myatomnum = []

answer = input()
length = len(answer)
intlength = int(length)

mm = []

for x in range(length):
    if (answer[x] > 'A' and answer[x] < 'Z') :
        for i in range (9):
            if (answer[x] == atom[i]):
                myatom.append(atommass[i])
    else :
        for ii in range (10):
            if (answer[x] == ii):
                myatomnum.append(ii)

for plus in range(int(intlength/2)):
    mm.append(int(myatom[plus])*int(myatomnum[plus]))

result = 0
for x in mm:
    result += x
print(result)
```

Makefile:6: recipe for target 'py3_run' failed
make: *** [py3_run] Error 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/goorm/Main.out", line 24, in 
mm.append(int(myatom[plus])*int(myatomnum[plus]))
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please format your code with code blocks for readability.

Comment: sorry;-; ill do that right away

Comment: For information, a code block can be created using the following syntax: \`\`\`\nYour code\n\`\`\`, with `\n` being a line break. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) under "Syntax highlighting for code"

Comment: OK found it. `if (answer[x] == ii)` compares a string (answer[x]) with an integer (ii). Thus you are not filling your list. `if (answer[x] == str(ii))`  will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand what your code was doing, so I rewrote it from scratch:

```
while True:
    atomWeights = {'H': 1, 'B': 10.8, 'C': 12, 'N': 14, 'O': 16, 'F': 19, 'P': 31, 'S': 32, 'K': 39.1}
    print("Enter chemical formula:")
    formula = input()
    length = len(formula)
    numberString = ""
    atomChar = ""
    weight = 0
    for i in range(length):
        if formula[i] in atomWeights:
            if len(atomChar) != 0:
                if len(numberString) != 0:
                    weight += atomWeights[atomChar] * int(numberString)
                else:
                    weight += atomWeights[atomChar]
            atomChar = formula[i]
            numberString = ""
        else:
            numberString += formula[i]
    if len(atomChar) != 0:
        if len(numberString) != 0:
            weight += atomWeights[atomChar] * int(numberString)
        else:
            weight += atomWeights[atomChar]
    print("The weight is:")
    print(weight)
    print()
```

Hope this helps! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
mm.append(int(myatom[plus])*int(myatomnum[plus]))
```

myatomnum index out of range, because the list is empty.

The problem is with the following if condition:

```
if (answer[x] == ii):
    myatomnum.append(ii)
```

There is a comparison of a character from the answer with an integer.
To fix it just take an integer of the character, as follows:

```
if (int(answer[x]) == ii):
    myatomnum.append(ii)
```